# Google AppEngine: understanding datastore transactions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I've recently faced this annoying problem with GAE inability to handle more than one entity group in a single transaction. Java pseudo-code below:

```
public void doit(EntityManager em, long id)
{
  Customer c = null;

  em.getTransaction().begin();

  if (id != 0)
    c = em.find(Customer.class, id);

  boolean create = (c == null);

  if (create)
    c = new Customer();

  c.setName("John Doe");

  if (create)
    em.persist(c);

  em.getTransaction().commit();  
}
```

The purpose was to update customer data if the record exists, otherwise create it. I ended up with an exception complaining about multiple entity groups in transaction. It would not allow finding/updating 2 different customers in one transaction as these entities belong to different entity groups.
So here is my (general) question:
Suppose I have a banking application with account entities having balance field. I want to transfer money from one account to another within a transaction of course to ensure noone updates both account balances during the transfer and in case of transfer failure i need to rollback everything. Does the scenario above even possible with GAE?

---

**Update:** when trying XG transactions (see the answer below) with the local dev GAE server remember to add the following to VM execution command (otherwise it won't work):

```
-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use XG transactions (cross group transactions)
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions

Comment: According to Google's doc "Entity group relationships tell App Engine to store several entities in the same part of the distributed network". So, your suggestion while being very straightforward would be the scalability killer...

Comment: Yess, I'm editing my answer to add that already and to add a better suggestion, but it's taking longer than I thought, because I'm not sure about some of the details.

Comment: I guess I found a better sollution :p

Comment: It's the best! Missed this one in the doc as usual...   Thank you!